# Probability of $x$ and $y$ to be in a group out of $2$ groups.

Tags: probability

In a class of $40$ there are two groups. One of $25$ people and the other of $15$. Find the probability that two particular students $x$ and $y$  are in same group.

Comment: This is not really a probability problem if the groups are fixed in composition as are indeed the two students:  either x and y belong to the same group or they don't. What you really mean is that two subgroups are created at _random_ by choosing $25$ out of the $40$, and then we ask for the probability that both x and y belong to the same group, whether it is the chosen $25$ or the rejected $15$.

Comment: It could also be stated as having two fixed groups of sizes 25 and 15, then choosing two random students out of the entire class of 40.

Comment: The probability that $x$ is in group A is $\frac{25}{40}$. **Given** that she is, the probability $y$ also is in group A is $\frac{24}{39}$. So the probability they are both in A is $\frac{25}{40}\cdot\frac{24}{39}$. Do the same for group B, and add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $\binom{40}{25}$ possible groups in total.

There are $\binom{38}{23}$ groups where x and y are both in the larger group and $\binom{38}{25}$ groups where x and y are both in the smaller group.

Hence, the probability that x and y are in the same group is $$\frac{\binom{38}{23}+\binom{38}{25}}{\binom{40}{25}}=\frac{27}{52}.$$